# SSIS Execute sql task

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis

I have created EXECUTE SQL TASK in the SSIS package.
I am getting the Error called "INSERT failed because the following SET options have incorrect settings:

> "ARITHABORT. Varify the set option are correct for use with indexed
>   views and/or indexes on computed columns or filtered indexes and query
>   notification"

But when i am trying execute ditectly in to SQL server management studio.It wont give any error.

Please let me know if you guys has come across this kind of issue.

Thanks

Comment: Please show the query put in the Task

Comment: When you are running the query in management studio, it has already established values for `ARITHABORT`, ansi_nulls and other things. Please do update your question with your query

Answer (score 0):

SET ARITHABORT in conjunction with SET ANSI WARNINGS controls how divide by zero and overflow errors are handled.

If you want to ignore the overflow and divide by zero, use this in front of your batch:

SET ARITHABORT OFF
SET ANSI WARNINGS OFF

If your database compatibility level is 80 or earlier, SET ARITHABORT must be on.